# Why I see red crossed marked messages on CAN trace in CANoe?

Tags: can-bus, canoe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zojqW.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wugvh.jpg)

here is the image. When I run CANoe for my configuration, I see some messages are red crossed visually. I don't know why it is? But it doesn't block my work, everything seems working fine. What is the meaning of such representations on CAN trace?
Thanks!

Comment: That usually means its an error frame. Can you post the complete picture of that frame (the complete line with all the CAN columns).

Comment: @Shyam
I have added on my original description above, sorry I don't have rights to add as a picture currently.
Also, I am sure, these red crossed messages are not error message. because CAN bus still works. Thanks

Comment: Are you using CANaero by any chance? Because the icons could mean that there is a protocol related error in the received frame.

Comment: I am using CANoe version 14. Okay, then it could be just an indication about protocol related issue. Even though it does not cause any blockage to my setup, I was curious about it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Shyam, I found out the reason for it. It's because I have already a CAN channel2 added in my simulation which I no longer use. But, when i use the channel 2 of vector CAN interface to listen to another can bus, these messages comes with small red crossed messages. When I remove the unused CAN channel 2 from my simulation, there are no longer red crossed marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was CAN2 present in my simulation setup which I do not use anymore, so when I use channel 2 to listen to another bus, messages coming in channel 2 shows the small red marks. Therefore, I removed the unused CAN2 from my simulation and all these small red marks are now gone.. I found it just today. thanks.